# groovy - how to work with multiple point numbers?

Tags: java, groovy

Working on a groovy script which will calculate the current product release version  by increment the previous version.
But the version has multiple points to it like 1.2.0 and need to increment it with another multi point number like 0.1.0, how to achieve in groovy, as it seems there is no such data type.

Comment: Use case please? what have you tried?

Comment: Use case is to calculate the next release version of product from CI by getting the last release version(tag) from git repo. Release version is something like 3 digits one 1.2.0, i have tried something like this which works , but i am looking if there is a generic way to do the same,                       
 ```def last_ver = "1.2.0"
def new_ver = (((my_ver.tokenize(".")[0] + "." + my_ver.tokenize(".")[1]).toFloat() + "0.1".toFloat()).round(2)) + "." + "0"```

Comment: Why don't you just break the multiple point number(String) into multiple numbers (Split it by dot) and then do additional operations on them and just convert it to a multiple point number again by joining them as a string?

Comment: @adn.911 that is what i am doing already, see the above comment. But i was checking if there is some other way which quite simple and generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like this. Does this help?

```
class Version {  

static final int INCREMENT_UNIT = 1;

int major, minor, point;  

Version(String version) {
    String parts[] = version.split(".");

    this.major = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    this.minor = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    this.point = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
 }

 Version incrementMajor(int unit) {
    this.major += unit; 

    return this;
 }

 Version incrementMinor(int unit) {
    this.minor += unit; 

    return this;
 }

 Version incrementPoint(int unit) {
    this.point += unit;

    return this; 
 }

String toString() {
    return major + "." + minor + "." + point;
}

}
```